# Polar projection with 3 axis in matplotlib/plotly/bokeh for Python? (Hive plots)

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, plotly, bokeh

Is there any tweak to the polar projection that allows for 3 axis? I guess possibly a 3D scatterplot tilted onto 2D so it lines up like this?

I recently found out about [Hive Plots](https://github.com/ericmjl/hiveplot) and I wanted to try to code one up so I could have more free-range on the asthetics to make it look more like [these guys](http://www.hiveplot.net/). I started trying to make one but the only way I could think of doing it was with polar coordinates like this.

My question:
**Is there a way to get 3 axis polar coordinates in matplotlib, plotly, or bokeh?**
or if not
**Is there a way to fix a 3D plot to have this type of structure?**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(2*[np.pi/2], [0,1], color="black", linewidth=3)
ax.plot(2*[5*np.pi/4], [0,1], color="black", linewidth=3)
ax.plot(2*[7*np.pi/4], [0,1], color="black", linewidth=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The link to your targeted aesthetics appears to be broken, so apologies if this doesn't actually help, but I maintain a package called [hiveplotlib](https://pypi.org/project/hiveplotlib/) that allows for plotting hive plots with flexibility on kwargs.

There's a [high-level API](https://geomdata.gitlab.io/hiveplotlib/quick_hive_plots.html) designed to satisfy most needs, plus there's a low level API for niche cases, [demonstrated on the Zachary's Karate Club dataset](https://geomdata.gitlab.io/hiveplotlib/karate_club.html).

Currently, there is only formal support for `matplotlib` and `bokeh`, but there's a JSON-exporter that allows for downstream plotting in any language, including an example with `plotly`, all of which is demonstrated in [this notebook](https://geomdata.gitlab.io/hiveplotlib/hive_plot_viz_outside_matplotlib.html).

Comment: Damn, that's a very clean package!  I've been maitaining this package but yours is much more mature (https://github.com/jolespin/hive_networkx).  Will definitely explore yours when I get some time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a start, but I would check out matplotlib 2.0 to see if 3D is better now

```
import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Lin3dSeg(a,b):
    '''
    if a, b are spherical coordinate vector tuples, then it
    returns list of spherical coordinate points of a linear in r, theta, phi
    3D spiral segment connecting them   
    ''' 
    return [np.linspace(start, stop) for start, stop in zip(a,b)]

def Sphere2Cart(sphere_pt): # no particular convention, just thrown together
    x = sphere_pt[0] * np.sin(sphere_pt[1])
    y = sphere_pt[0] * np.cos(sphere_pt[1])
    z = sphere_pt[0] * np.cos(sphere_pt[2])
    return (x, y, z)

def SphereSegCarts(seg):
    return [Sphere2Cart(pt) for pt in zip(*Lin3dSeg(*seg))]

seg_a =((10, 0, 0),(5, np.pi/2, 0))
seg_b =((10, np.pi/2, 0),(1, 0, np.pi/2))
seg_c =((3, 0, np.pi/2),(10, np.pi/2, np.pi/2))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(elev=45, azim=45)

ax.plot(*zip(*SphereSegCarts(seg_a)), c='r')
ax.plot(*zip(*SphereSegCarts(seg_b)), c='g')
ax.plot(*zip(*SphereSegCarts(seg_c)), c='b')

plt.show()
```

[image]